# Django. Model not showing up in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm making my first Django project, and I added a model in the template, but, when I'm running it, I don't see anything. but when I inspect the page, I see an h2 tag for each entry in the model.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse


class MyDate(models.Model):
    english_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    hebrew_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.hebrew_date
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView)
from luach.models import MyDate

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'new.html'

class MyDateListView(ListView):
    model = MyDate
    context_object_name = 'mydate'
```

template

```
{% extends 'luach/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="jumbotron">
    {% for mydate in mydate %}
      <h2>Hi{{ MyDate.hebrew_date }}</h2>
    {% empty %}
      <h2>Sorry, no dates in this list.</h2>    
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endblock  %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not passing the context to the template.
write like this:

```
return(request, 'noob/clueless-me.html' context)
```

in context:

```
context = {
  'my_date' : my_date,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your template:

```
{% for date in mydate %}
      <h2>Hi{{ date.hebrew_date }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

you can not use `MyDate`, you have to use your `context_object_name` : `mydate`

Comment: let me know if the above code works. The answer from djangotic won't work because your using Class based views insted of function based.. If it does not work, show us your ``urls.py`` please

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in your for statement in the template try this:

```
{% extends 'luach/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  {% for date in mydate %}
     <h2>Hi{{ date.hebrew_date }}</h2>
     {% empty %}
     <h2>Sorry, no dates in this list.</h2>    
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```